# AsihttpRequest didfinishselector decompression error iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

Hi I am downloading an epub file from my server of size (100-200 MB)
epub file is basically a zip file with extension "`.epub`"

Code which I am using to download the file:

```
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TempBookUrl]];

     bookZipPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

         NSString *tempStr = [bookZipPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp%@.epub",model.iD]];

            NSString *str = [bookZipPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.epub",model.iD]];

         [request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:tempStr];

         [request setDownloadDestinationPath:str];

         [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(processFile:)];

         [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
         [request setDelegate:self];
         [request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
         [request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
         [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
         [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];

         [request startAsynchronous];
```

After lots of downloading  I get the error

saying that unable to decompress the file as file do not exist at the temporary path.

> ERROR: Decompression of   /Users/admin/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/7.0/Applications/07322021-F878-41DA-A712-5C175C5252B6/Documents/temp27.epub

failed the file does not exist

I am using iOS 7

Comment: How are you using `ASIHttpRequest`? It isn't clear from the code.

Comment: What code is getting that error? The `processFile:` code? Is `requestWentWrong:` getting hit?

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is deprecated now. You should go to AFNetworking or any other networking framework.